# How to deploy JAX-RS Application in WAS 7.0.23?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, websphere, rad

I am using RAD and WAS 7.0.23, and try to deploy jax-rs in it. But I am getting below error in deployment descriptor(Web.xml).

> Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet
>   [com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet]: Could not find
>   required class - class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet

Servlet Mapping

```html
 <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>APPLICATION CLASS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Has the project been built with the back level of Java that is running under  WAS 7.0.2 ?

Comment: According to [IBM Support](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=U014343F68568M71), WAS v7.0 support ended on April 30, 2018.  WAS v8.0 is also out of support.  I would suggest attempting to deploy on a supported version of WAS - ideally WAS traditional v9.0 or WAS Liberty 18.0.0.3.  HTH, Andy

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS wasn't added to WAS until 8.0. If you want to use JAX-RS on that old a server (which I generally wouldn't recommend for the reason Andy mentioned above), you'll need to bring your own provider.

Comment: com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs-1.0.22.jar added to the build path. This jar contains IBMRestServlet class in it. But it still shows class not found exception.

Comment: Before 8.0, JAX-RS was available in the Web 2.0 Feature Pack. None of the links mentioned in this related question work now, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820912/jax-rs-without-jersey-on-was7

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree that continuing to use the well-out-of-support 7.0 is unwise.

That said, it may just be that you need to add the jar to the RAD project's "Deployment Assembly", in addition to the "Java Build Path".